# How do I accomplish the same thing without using a global variable?

Tags: python

`add_digits2(1)(3)(5)(6)(0)` should add up all the numbers and stop when it reaches `0`.
The output should be `15`

The below code works but uses a global variable.

```
total = 0
def add_digits2(num):
    global total
    if num == 0:
        print(total)
    else:
        total += num
        return add_digits2
```

The result is correct but needs to do the same thing without using the global variable.

Comment: curious question, is this homework? why are the values being passed that way?

Comment: its a test question, Im learning functions as return values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is use `partial`:

```
from functools import partial

def add_digits2(num, total=0):
    if num == 0:
        print(total)
        return
    else:
        total += num
        return partial(add_digits2, total=total)

add_digits2(2)(4)(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass in `*args` as a parameter and return the sum

```
def add_digits2(*args):
     return sum(args)

add_digits2(1, 3, 5 ,6)
```

Comment: @displayname - What do you mean?

Comment: Well, my answer using `partial` is something one would never do. Any sane person would use variable numbers of arguments as shown in your answer.

Comment: @displayname - Ah right yes, I went for the literal of "accomplishing the same thing without a global" :D

Comment: :D I went for backwards compatibility :P

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a class, using the `__call__` method to obtain this behavior:

```
class Add_digits:

    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0

    def __call__(self, val):
        if val != 0:
            self.total += val
            return self
        else:
            print(self.total)
            self.total = 0


add_digits = Add_digits()

add_digits(4)(4)(0)
# 8
add_digits(4)(6)(0)
# 10
```

though I still don't get why you would want to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to say what *they* are after when asking questions like that but the total could be stored in a function attribute. Something like this

```
>>> def f():
...     f.a = 3


>>> f()
>>> f.a
3
```